# Calculate the maximum minimum distance from a geo object to multipoint?

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0

I am working with `postgis 2.0` and I would like to calculate the maximum minimum distance from a point set (multipoint) to a polygon. It seems that neither `st_distance` nor `st_maxdistance` can meet my requirement. I know I can use `st_dumppoints` to change the point set to a point table and then calculate the maximum distance from the point table to the polygon, but I am still wondering whether there is some function like `st_maxmindist(multipt,polygon)` that can calculate the distance directly.

An example here:

```
geom 1: MULTIPOINT(139.64743 35.641438,139.647644 35.641396)
geom 2: POLYGON((139.6478008 35.6414487,139.6476882 35.6414682,139.6476906 35.6414786,139.6476412 35.6414874,139.6476386 35.6414768,139.6475749 35.6414879,139.6475559 35.6414234,139.64754 35.6414262,139.6475316 35.6413962,139.6475252 35.6413974,139.6475284 35.6414107,139.6474595 35.6414227,139.6474448 35.6413664,139.6475132 35.6413531,139.6475152 35.6413585,139.6475365 35.6413545,139.6475387 35.6413621,139.647766 35.6413201,139.6478008 35.6414487))

select st_distance(st_wkttosql('MULTIPOINT(139.64743 35.641438,139.647644 35.641396)'),
  st_wkttosql('POLYGON((139.6478008 35.6414487,139.6476882 35.6414682,139.6476906 35.6414786,139.6476412 35.6414874,139.6476386 35.6414768,139.6475749 35.6414879,139.6475559 35.6414234,139.64754 35.6414262,139.6475316 35.6413962,139.6475252 35.6413974,139.6475284 35.6414107,139.6474595 35.6414227,139.6474448 35.6413664,139.6475132 35.6413531,139.6475152 35.6413585,139.6475365 35.6413545,139.6475387 35.6413621,139.647766 35.6413201,139.6478008 35.6414487))'))

returns: 0

select st_maxdistance(st_wkttosql('MULTIPOINT(139.64743 35.641438,139.647644 35.641396)'),
  st_wkttosql('POLYGON((139.6478008 35.6414487,139.6476882 35.6414682,139.6476906 35.6414786,139.6476412 35.6414874,139.6476386 35.6414768,139.6475749 35.6414879,139.6475559 35.6414234,139.64754 35.6414262,139.6475316 35.6413962,139.6475252 35.6413974,139.6475284 35.6414107,139.6474595 35.6414227,139.6474448 35.6413664,139.6475132 35.6413531,139.6475152 35.6413585,139.6475365 35.6413545,139.6475387 35.6413621,139.647766 35.6413201,139.6478008 35.6414487))')
  );
returns 0.0003709543502758528

select st_distance((st_dumppoints(st_wkttosql('MULTIPOINT(139.64743 35.641438,139.647644 35.641396)'))).geom,
  st_wkttosql('POLYGON((139.6478008 35.6414487,139.6476882 35.6414682,139.6476906 35.6414786,139.6476412 35.6414874,139.6476386 35.6414768,139.6475749 35.6414879,139.6475559 35.6414234,139.64754 35.6414262,139.6475316 35.6413962,139.6475252 35.6413974,139.6475284 35.6414107,139.6474595 35.6414227,139.6474448 35.6413664,139.6475132 35.6413531,139.6475152 35.6413585,139.6475365 35.6413545,139.6475387 35.6413621,139.647766 35.6413201,139.6478008 35.6414487))')
  ) order by st_distance desc limit 1

returns: 0.00003323161144144182 (what I want is this result)
```

p.s. I think this distance is close to a simplification of Haussdorf distance, but directly using Haussdorf distance here cannot get the result:

```
select st_hausdorffdistance(st_wkttosql('MULTIPOINT(139.64743 35.641438,139.647644 35.641396)'),
  st_wkttosql('POLYGON((139.6478008 35.6414487,139.6476882 35.6414682,139.6476906 35.6414786,139.6476412 35.6414874,139.6476386 35.6414768,139.6475749 35.6414879,139.6475559 35.6414234,139.64754 35.6414262,139.6475316 35.6413962,139.6475252 35.6413974,139.6475284 35.6414107,139.6474595 35.6414227,139.6474448 35.6413664,139.6475132 35.6413531,139.6475152 35.6413585,139.6475365 35.6413545,139.6475387 35.6413621,139.647766 35.6413201,139.6478008 35.6414487))'))

returns: 0.00016541925521245188
```

Comment: both functions should do exactly what you need. please add the query you are using. if you can't pinpoint the problem, update your question with example data, too.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, sorry for not explaining it clearly, I have added an example in my question.

Comment: Your question seems to be "find closest distance to the polygon from any member of a multipoint geometry that is not inside the polygon" and I think that the ST_DumpPoints method is just right for you.

Comment: I see, but is there an easy function to do that? I am afraid using `ST_DumpPoints` for joining two tables would be a little complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that none of `ST_Distance`, `ST_MaxDistance` or `ST_HausdorffDistance` will meet your requirement.  `ST_HausdorffDistance` is closest, but the problem with it is that it is symmetric, which means that a very large polygon will dominate the result.  What you really need is the oriented Hausdorff Distance.  JTS has an [implementation](https://github.com/locationtech/jts/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/locationtech/jts/algorithm/distance/DiscreteHausdorffDistance.java#L110) of this, but unfortunately PostGIS does not expose the GEOS equivalent.

So the only option is to use the `ST_Dump/ORDER BY` method.  It should be possible to do this over multiple rows by using a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I understood the question somehow wrong but for me the functions seem fit your requirements.

```
select st_distance(
st_geomfromtext(
'MULTIPOINT (( -80 20 ), ( -40 0 ))'),
st_geomfromtext(
'POLYGON (( 20 0, 60 40, 80 -20, 20 0 ))'))

Result:60

select st_maxdistance(
st_geomfromtext(
'MULTIPOINT (( -80 20 ), ( -40 0 ))'),
st_geomfromtext(
'POLYGON (( 20 0, 60 40, 80 -20, 20 0 ))'))

Result:164.924225024706
```

Image showing the geometries and minimum-maximum distances

[image]

Your geometries look like this

[image]

Minimum distance is zero because one part of the multipoint is inside the polygon. What distance are you actually trying to find?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sorry for not explaining it clearly, I have added an example in my question.